# How to save a list in python?

Tags: python, json, list, save, pickle

I have a list composed by many matrices.
I would save this list in order to read it in another script.
This is my code t save my list W:

```
with open("My_rotation_matrix.bin", "wb") as output:
    pickle.dump(W, output)
```

And then to read my list in another script:

```
with open("My_rotation_matrix.bin", "rb") as data:
W = pickle.load(data)
```

The problem is that the saved My_rotation_matrix.bin is huge (1.4 GB) and when I read my list I have to wait almost 5 minutes. 
Is there a faster way to save/read a list in python? For example using JSON?
Thanks!

Comment: You may want to take a look at the HDF5 file format in conjunction with the Python packages *pytables* and *h5py*.

Comment: *"Can you write the right code?"* - you have profoundly misunderstood what Stack Overflow is for...

Comment: I'm working with python from few weeks. I need to an efficient way to save and read data. I don't think my question is a bad question. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: What is contained within the list? Are all the items, integers, or is it a mixture of types, nested lists etc..?

Comment: Take a look at [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)

Comment: The list contains 180 numpy matrices. Each matrix is a 512x512 matrix and it is composed by floating point numbers.

Comment: Could you accept my answer if you are happy with it please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion is if you can work with numpy. Since already have your data in a list you can just do this:

```
    import numpy as np
    data = np.array(mylist)
    np.savez("Myfile", data)
```

Now it might take a minute or two to save this file (depending on how much RAM you have on your computer) but loading the file is rather quick, (just a few seconds for a file that was 700 MB). When you are ready to load it you can just say

```
    a = np.load("Myfile.npz") #make sure you use the .npz!
    b = a['arr_0']
```

Comment: After two weeks with no problem, suddenly now when I try to load my file, program stops since a memory error occurs.
Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: This is my question: you can read all details. Thanks.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31653558/error-saving-and-loading-a-list-of-matrices/31653880?noredirect=1#comment51254122_31653880