# Error saving and loading a list of matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a list "data_list", and I would save it in order to load it in another script.
First of all I converted it in an array, in this way:

```
data_array = np.array(data_list)
```

Then I saved it:

```
np.savez("File", data_array)
```

Then, in another script I want to access to "File"; so:

```
a = np.load("File.npz") 
b = a['arr_0']
```

I used this code until two weeks ago and it worked fine. In these days I am trying to work with my program, but it ends with an error identified in the line

b = a['arr_0']

"File" is a 300 MB file. The strangest thing is that it has stopped suddenly to work.
Any idea about what can be happened?

Ps: I give you some information. My list contains 180 matrices 511x511. Each matrix contains decimal numbers (I tried to create 180 matrices of zeros, and the error occurs in the same way). If I reduce the number of matrices, the script works fine: in particular down to 130 matrices it is ok, while up to the program doesn't work.
Here I report the error message

```
        b = a['arr_0']
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 241, in     
    __getitem__
        return format.read_array(value)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\format.py", line 459, in   
    read_array
        array = numpy.fromstring(data, dtype=dtype, count=count)
    MemoryError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MemoryError`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/exceptions.html#MemoryError) is an out of memory condition. This explains why it happens with objects of at least a certain size - more and bigger arrays, as you would expect, require more memory. What the max size is, and why it seems to have changed, is harder. This can be highly specific to your system, especially in regard to considerations like:

- How much memory (physical RAM and swap space) exists and is available to the operating system
- How much virtual memory the OS gives to Python
- How much of that you're already using
- The implementation of the C library, especially of its `malloc` function, which can affect how Python uses the memory it is allocated

And possibly quite a few other things.

Per the comments, it seems the biggest problem here is that you are running a 32 bit build of Python. On Windows, 32 bit processes [apparently have an effective maximum memory address space of around 2GB](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2010-February/010113.html). By my tests, the list of arrays you are using by itself might take around a quarter of that. The fact that your error only comes up when reading the file back in suggests that numpy deserialisation is relatively memory intensive, but I don't know enough about its implementation to be able to say why that would be. In any case, it seems like installing a 64 bit build of Python is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I don't understand is that if I work with my list composed by many matrices (in a script), why I can't work with the same data loading it in another script? If it was a true memory error I couldn't create the list. But I can.

Comment: If creating it standalone still works, but reading it in (using a different script on the same Python interpreter on the same computer) doesn't, that could be related to what else the second script is also doing, or even some artifact of how numpy deserialises arrays. Check your system's memory usage after you successfully create your amazingly massive list of arrays - it'll probably be quite portion of your system memory.

Comment: Absolutely not. Memory uses 2.5 GB/7.9 GB both before than after loading my list. Inserting raw_input() between load command and the access changes nothing in the memoty usage.

Comment: [This mailing list post](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-win32/2010-February/010113.html) details how per-process memory limits work on Windows, in a 32 bit context (you almost certainly are on a 64 bit OS to have 8GB available RAM, but you could still be running a 32 bit Python for some reason). It suggests that there's a limit of around 2GB available per process. Inserting an input in the program won't change much, especially if you don't keep the resulting string around. See if you can duplicate the error by creating something *big*, like an extra super massive np array.

Comment: Although a quick test suggests that 180 511 * 511 arrays should take less than 400MB, even accounting for the overhead of having them in a list. So my best guess is that numpy's deserialisation routine takes quite a bit of 'extra' memory as working space.

Comment: Searching in the web, I had found something like this. Exactly as you said, I'm running a 32 bit Python (I don't know why, and I don't know if I can force to work a 64 bit Python).
My fault, but I have not understood what you suggest me.

Comment: I've updated my answer to mention the 32/64 bit issue; installing 64 bit Python seems like the best option. The [download page for windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) does list 64-bit builds.

Comment: Last comment: thank you very much for your answers. I have yet intsalled all packages with 32 bit, so I prefer to search another way to save and load big data. I had yet tested Pickle and Json, but they were too slow. But now I'm trying to use h5py and it seems works well. 
But I am happy to know that I have also this possibility.